# Electron App prompts 'Accessibility Features' Approval on Mac

Tags: electron, macos-catalina, accessibility-api

When Electron App is installed for the first time, it prompts for Accessibility Features Approval on Mac. 
Is it possible to find for what app's feature approval is needed? If not, can I disable it in code?
There is no any accessibility features in the code that I am aware of.

Comment: I've never seen this in a few years of developing apps on/for macOS. Does it happen even with a vanilla "hello world" test project?

Comment: I am not sure about vanilla project, will get back to you when I check that. But it is not such unusual behaviour of the electrons app. Slack, Discord, Visual Studio Code, they are all built on electron and demands accessibility features approval.

Comment: Are you running Mojave? 
[Why does macOS say that Atom wants to access my calendar, contacts, photos, etc.?](https://discuss.atom.io/t/why-does-macos-say-that-atom-wants-to-access-my-calendar-contacts-photos-etc/59291)